# Beginners problem with WebMatrix Tags that don't work

Tags: tags, webmatrix

Beginner, trying to learn to MS Web Matrix.

href, style, header, footer, tags don't seem to work.

Even copied and pasted coding from Web Dev 101 part 3 instructions on the "Learn About Web Matrix" site to be sure syntax was correct.

Is there some source for answers about Web Matrix programing problems.
Certainly no way to get anything through Micro Soft.

Every time I download the latest version of Web Matrix something gets fixed, but I'm weary of trying things that just don't work as shown in "Learning" documentation.

Is there some source for questions that a novice could direct such basic questions to, I'd sure like to know.

Thanks,

olearyevergreen

Comment: can you define "don't seem to work"?  Assuming you are building a .cshtml file somewhere, you should be able to use straight HTML (no code at all) and it would process just like an .html.  Not what you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You can post questions here, or at the [WebMatrix forum at www.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/1224.aspx/1?WebMatrix).

When you do, make sure you are specific. Explain what your problem is exactly and post details of any error message you might get, and relevant source code.